# Show echo in previous php file

Tags: php, echo

I'm Probably searching with the wrong keywords, but I can not find the correct answer.

I have a php file(overview.php) which contains a button, this button executes another php script(mailinfo.php) which sends a email and shows a echo line when successful .

```
<input onclick="location.href = 'mailinfo.php';" type="button" value="Nee" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
```

When I click the button, mail.php is loaded and i only see the echo. I would like to see this echo on overview.php without showing the mail.php page.

Comment: This code may load `mailinfo.php` but it does not pass anything useful to that script

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-side code. Your button is on the client. Your button cannot "execute" a PHP file. It can trigger navigation to another page (as your code is currently doing) or send an AJAX request to `mailinfo.php` on the server.

It sounds like you are looking for an AJAX solution. You can read more about AJAX here: https://www.wired.com/2010/02/ajax_for_beginners/
Or here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/

Comment: This is really just a comment it is certainly not an answer

Comment: Is there an "answer" to this?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your overview.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.btn-danger').on('click', function(e){

    $.ajax({
      url: 'mailinfo.php',
      success: function(data, status) {
          $('body').html('<p><em>success!</em></p>');
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
      }
    }); // end ajax call
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a successful result in the URI when passing back to the overview.php file.

In your mailinfo.php file, put something like this if the result is successful.

```
if($result) {           
header("Location: ../overview.php?result=success");
} else
header("Location: ../overview.php?result=failed");
}
```

Then in your overview.php file, get the info from the URI, like:

```
$result = $_GET['result'];
$success = "success";
if ($result = $success) {
echo "Success";
}
else {
echo "Failed";
}
```

You might need to make a few adjustments, but should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Do it in javascript :

```js
  function mailinfo() {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        var text = document.createTextNode('Your text go here');
        p.appendChild(text);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
        // If you want to give a class or id 
        p.className = "text-center";
    }
```

```html
<input onclick='mailinfo()' type="button" value="Nee" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
```